# Is it possible to supply named rest arguments in the type space in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, we can use a Tuple of types to create typesafe rest arguments:

```js
type Params = [string,number,string]

const fn = (...args: Params) => null

// Type is (args_0: string, args_1: number, args_2: string) => null
```

Is there any way to supply the *names* of these parameters? Completely in the Type space?

So, instead of having the parameters named `args_0`, `args_1`, `args_2`, I want to explicitly name them (example) `myString`, `myNumber`, `mySecondString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuple members can be named, which *just works* when spread to function arguments:

```
type Params = [myString: string, myNumber: number, mySecondString: string]

const fn = (...args: Params) => null
// const fn: (myString: string, myNumber: number, mySecondString: string) => null
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQNrJAZWAQEsA7AcwC4pUizyAaKPAOQFdkAjCBa0j7giZ58EAMYB7UgBNCJCtVrzyAXQBQayaVpQAZqUxQAFADozicqmrwkaAJSYAfFH4AbV2oD0nqFp37qIxE6BRoQxmYQdi4ePgEeYQJxKVlwxXCHDGc3VyA)

Comment: thanks! this answers the question, but I realized my real issue was with mapped tuples. Made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861911/is-mapped-named-tuple-members-possible-in-typescript